# Does Svelte provide a TypeScript type for input change events?

Tags: typescript, svelte

Given the following sample code for a file input

```
<script lang="ts">
function onFileSelected(event) {
    const file: File = event.target.files[0];

    // ...
}
</script>

<input type="file" on:change={onFileSelected} />
```

I would like to add a type to the parameter `event` ( instead of `any` ). I tried [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) and [InputEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/InputEvent) but both don't know about the `files` field.

I'm looking for something like `Svelte.ChangeEvent<HTMLFileInputElement>`. Is there something I could use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Svelte has internal types, but it might not be the best idea to use them as they could change. They type the handler as a whole, which could be done like this for example:

```js
const onFileSelected: svelte.JSX.EventHandler<Event, HTMLInputElement> = e => {
    if (e.currentTarget.files == null)
        return; // files can be null, handle however appropriate

    const file = e.currentTarget.files[0];
};
```

(The types do not affect `target`, which in many cases cannot be typed definitively. E.g. for a `click` event it can be any descendant of the element with the handler. Use `currentTarget` instead.)

You can also just do something similar yourself:

```js
function onFileSelected(e: Event & { currentTarget: HTMLInputElement }) {
  // ...
}
```

This could then also be extracted to a generic type alias:

```js
type ElementEvent<T extends Element> = Event & { currentTarget: T }
```

(`Event` could also be made a parameter, in case a more specific event is used.)

Comment: Webstorm still comes up with `Unresolved variable files` when using `e: Event & { currentTarget: HTMLInputElement }` but the build seems to work. However, `svelte.JSX.EventHandler<Event, HTMLInputElement>` works "better" ( Webstorm knows about the files property )

Comment: Typescript define the following types over `Event`: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-DOM-lib-generator/blob/f85d145348fc853bc7fecea5e5925c66a2e0e0b6/inputfiles/addedTypes.jsonc#LL54C24-L54C24

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
<script lang="ts">
  function onFileSelected(event: Event) {
    const target = event.target as unknown as { files: File[] };
    const file: File = target?.files[0];
  }
</script>      
<main>
  <input type="file" on:change={onFileSelected} />
</main>
```

And the red squeegee lines will go away.